# How to align text within parent div

Tags: css

So I have the class:

```
awpcp-subtitle.
```

Within this I want to target a child element, which I can with:

```
 @media (max-width: 1920px) and (min-width: 769px) {
       .awpcp-subtitle:nth-of-type(1) {
           margin-top: 440px!Important;
       }
 }
```

This enables me to move it up and down. But I want to align the text which floats left at the moment and:

```
@media (max-width: 1920px) and (min-width: 769px) {
       .awpcp-subtitle:nth-of-type(1) {
            text-align: center!Important;
       }
}
```

Doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Here is html:

```
<div class="awpcp-subtitle">Contact Information</div>
<a href="https://adsler.co.uk/wp-user-test-dashboard- 
2/awpcp-reply-to-ad/21/old-goriot-balzac/">Email 
admin</a><a href="tel:<br/><label>Phone:</label> 
07576335122"><div class="phone"><br/><label>Phone: 
</label> 07576335122</div> </a>
<a href="http://maps.google.com/?q=:<br/>. 
<label>Location:</label> Westminster, London, UK"><div 
class="location"><br/><label>Location:</label> 
Westminster, London, UK</div></a>           
<div class="visit-website"><Visit Website:</div>                            
</div>
<div class="showawpcpadpage"><label>Price:</label> 
<strong>£ 0.99</strong></div>

                            <div class="fixfloat"></div>

                            <div class="showawpcpadpage">
                                <div class="awpcp-subtitle">More Information</div>
```

Comment: 'text that floats left' . Means that it has `text-align:left` ? and also with this selector `.awpcp-subtitle:nth-of-type(1)` you do not select a child element of `.awpcp-subtitle` as you say in your question. Anyway, how can we help you if you do not replicate your problem here using minimal code

Comment: Yes. Perhaps not clear. As i understand there is no text-align:left on: awpcp-subtitle:nth-of-type(1) so I've no idea why it's left of centre

Comment: ' as i understand ' . So you cannot see what styles are applied ? check in dev tools. And also, please post some code that replicates your problem. Otherwise we cannot help you

Comment: But i did just that. I selected part of the div class awpcp-subtitle, which was awpcp-subtitle:nth-of-type(1), and managed to move it up and down using px

Comment: There is nothing making it align left. It shouldn't be, but it is...

Comment: what is it your trying to align center? elements are aligned to the left by default, and some elements wont be affected by text-align. For example, an image wont be affected by text-align, unless the text-align is set to the parent element containing the image. [and the image is set to display:block;]

Comment: Again. I need to insist you share code that REPLICATES your existing problem. `awpcp-subtitle:nth-of-type(1) ` does NOT select a specific child of ` awpcp-subtitle` . It selects a specific `awpcp-subtitle` . THe first of it's type.

Comment: @Moose please see 'contact information' on this page. https://adsler.co.uk/wp-user-test-dashboard-2/awpcp-show-ad/21/old-goriot-balzac/london/uk/westminster/books/ please view on PC if poss as the site is responsive.

Comment: @Mihai T shared html. Is OK?

Comment: Let me ask you this way. Just with the code you shared in this question. If you put it in a snippet, can you replicate your exact problem ?

Comment: I've just a novice. That's why I'm asking. It seems that the HTML code posted relates to the css. Specifically 'contact Information' as listed in above html. Further than that, you've lost me....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right so basically after looking at the pages code via the link you provided, its a simple case of rearranging the order of your HTML elements.

in the section div section - showawpcpadpage you need to move the awpcp-subtitle [Contact Information] to the top, instead of being under the image + links.

```
<div class="showawpcpadpage">
<div class="awpcp-subtitle">Contact Information</div>
<div class="awpcp-ad-primary-image">
<a class="awpcp-listing-primary-image-thickbox-link thickbox thumbnail" href="https://adsler.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/awpcp/images/19808423-2b60d824-large.jpg" rel="awpcp-gallery-21">
    <img class="thumbshow" src="https://adsler.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/awpcp/thumbs/19808423-2b60d824-primary.jpg" alt="Thumbnail for the listing's main image" width="200" height="200">
</a>
```

that's what your HTML flow should look like.

The layout of your HTML is important. So if for example, if your header is at the top of the page, the HTML for the header should also be at the top of the page, not several elements down.

Comment: I didn't realise that the layout/order affected it. Thanks

Comment: That's the only way of doing it? I can't manipulate with CSS?

Comment: I'm sure you're right though so I'll mark your answer correct.

Comment: Yeah, thats the easiest way of doing it, and the best way. Not need to add lots of dodgy CSS code when all you need to do it swap a HTML element around. Yes layout order is important. Imagine it like how words in a book is laid out. Left to right working your way down the page. You really should right your HTML elements out in the order the appear on the page, just like in the book example, you wouldnt put the last sentence at the top of the page and the first at the bottom!